# Laravel Fortify modify RegisterViewResponse

Tags: laravel

I am trying to modify the behavior of Fortify Register route.
I am sending out custom register urls, if this url doesn't match my logic I need to redirect to a custom page, so you can not even enter `/register`.

But I am only getting a 302 redirect loop for `/register`.
[image]

To do so I created a `RegisterViewResponse` to override default behavior:

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\RegisterViewResponse as RegisterViewResponseContract;

class RegisterViewResponse implements RegisterViewResponseContract
{

    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        $canEnter = true;

        if($canEnter){
            return redirect()->intended('/register');
        } else {
            return redirect()->intended("/otherPage");
        }

    }

}
```

I also added this to `FortifyServiceProvider`:
`$this->app->singleton(RegisterViewResponse::class,Responses\RegisterViewResponse::class)`

Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: Thats exactly what you wrote. You returned intended redirect to `/register` on `/register` route

Comment: @TymurValiiev if I remove `/register` redirect, I get  a white blank register page instead

Comment: so you should return something. i dont know what exactly, maybe view or something usefull